# Laser printing clear plastics

Tags: color, print-design

I have a hp officejet6500Aplus and  my grandson wants to do a project on the family tree. He has drawn his story and now wants to print on go clear laminate / transparent so he can project his story on the wall.  Ive tried the transparent sheets but they come out wet. Would laminate or even an acetone sheet bd bdtter? Your help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

The problem with inkjets here is they use **ink**... not toner (or wax). So, they *will* be wet. You need to let them sit and dry.

Most of the transparent printer sheets are designed for *toner* that is dry dust and gets baked in so it solidifies.

I don't think you'll find any relevant solution for transparencies and an inkjet printer. You may be better off putting a PDF on a thumb drive and heading to your local Kinko's or copy shop and asking them to print it on transparencies. (Because they'll use a toner or wax printer, not an inkjet.)

Answer (score 1):

Search for Inkjet Printable Transparency Film. There are several options available. Some of them claim to be dry in few seconds.

I have not tried them, but I believe it to be possible, because also glossy photo printing papers dry soon - maybe not in a second, but soon enough.

If you happen to be stayed around long enough to have handled photo film negatives, you may remember, that the emulsion side sucked all wet dirt very easily, but the plastic side didn't. The inkjet transparency film must have a coating that resembles the gelatine emulsion in the old camera films.